# restart python (or reload modules) in py.test tests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a (python3) package that has completely different behaviour depending on how it's `init()`ed (perhaps not the best design, but rewriting is not an option). The module can only be `init()`ed once, a second time gives an error. I want to test this package (both behaviours) using py.test.

Note: the nature of the package makes the two behaviours mutually exclusive, there is no possible reason to ever want both in a singular program.

I have serveral `test_xxx.py` modules in my test directory. Each module will init the package in the way in needs (using fixtures). Since `py.test` starts the python interpreter once, running all test-modules in one py.test run fails.

Monkey-patching the package to allow a second `init()` is not something I want to do, since there is internal caching etc that might result in unexplained behaviour.

- Is it possible to tell py.test to run each test module in a separate python process (thereby not being influenced by inits in another test-module)
- Is there a way to reliably reload a package (including all sub-dependencies, etc)?
- Is there another solution (I'm thinking of importing and then unimporting the package in a fixture, but this seems excessive)?

Comment: I have no experience with it but you may be able to use / adapt this plugin to start several subprocesses and do things that way: https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html#running-tests-in-a-python-subprocess

Comment: If it is possible to run pytest on one file (`pytext text/text_xyz.py), then you could write a program to find the test_xyz files and run each in a separate process with the subprocess module.  This is what the plugin referenced by Simeon should be doing.

Comment: Thanks. Looked at `pytest-xdist`, it unfortunately doesn't start a new subprocess per module. Indeed right now I have the test-modules in 2 directories: one that uses one way of initing, the other using the other. Then I run pytest once per directory. However it's unfortunate that then I need an extra script to make sure the return values and test reports of the individual runs get combined.

Comment: @Claude specifically, does the xdist `--boxed` option not do what you want?

Comment: @pfctdayelise: thanks! It does work indeed, I should have tested that option (although documentation only mentions it as protection from SEGFAULTs, I should have thought a bit longer on how it does that). Disadvantage is that it restarts python for every single test, not just once per module. Perhaps I should dive a bit further into pytest-xdist, see if I can hack it a bit toward what I need.

Comment: [xdist `--boxed` is no longer](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/468), and it has been extracted to a low-maintenance separate repository. See the release notes: https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html.

Answer (score 5):

To reload a module, try using the `reload()` from library `importlib`

Example:

```
from importlib import reload
import some_lib
#do something
reload(some_lib)
```

Also, launching each test in a new process is viable, but multiprocessed code is kind of painful to debug.

Example

```
import some_test
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

#create new return value holder, in this case a list
manager = Manager()
return_value = manager.list()
#create new process
process =  Process(target=some_test.some_function, args=(arg, return_value))
#execute process
process.start()
#finish and return process
process.join()
#you can now use your return value as if it were a normal list, 
#as long as it was assigned in your subprocess
```

Comment: I'm using python3 so `imp` should be `importlib`. Reloading a module this way (unfortunately) does not clear the global dictionary for that module, so it doesn't help. Also it does not reload all dependent modules I'm afraid. Your running each test in a new process looks interesting but I don't see how this combines with `py.test`. Also I need each *module* to run in a separate test, not each function.

Comment: @Claude, say you are running a test, and you realize, that you have to make some changes to the test code, otherwise the test wont work. `importlib` will reload other modules called by the test function, but is there a way to reload the test_function itself, when you are stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: I don't think so. Also, I wouldn't see how this would work, how would it know where the code-pointer would be.

Comment: Just used `--forked` from pytest-xdist. Then you can still debug specific test cases by omitting the flag

Answer (score 4):

Delete all your module imports and also your tests import that also import your modules:

```py
import sys

for key in list(sys.modules.keys()):
    if key.startswith("your_package_name") or key.startswith("test"):
        del sys.modules[key]
```

you can use this as a fixture by configuring on your `conftest.py` file a fixture using the `@pytest.fixture` decorator.

Comment: This saved my day. Do pay attention that sometimes your package is a subpackage and you should then use the full package path. I tried to delete the "login" package but actually had to delete the "project.login" package. Conclusion: when using fixtures import statements are not re-ran...

Comment: Is this very safe?

Answer (score 1):

Once I had similar problem, quite bad design though..

```
@pytest.fixture()
def module_type1():
    mod = importlib.import_module('example')
    mod._init(10)
    yield mod
    del sys.modules['example']

@pytest.fixture()
def module_type2():
    mod = importlib.import_module('example')
    mod._init(20)
    yield mod
    del sys.modules['example']


def test1(module_type1)
    pass

def test2(module_type2)
    pass
```

The example/**init**.py had something like this

```
def _init(val):
    if 'sample' in globals():
        logger.info(f'example already imported, val{sample}' )
    else:
        globals()['sample'] = val
        logger.info(f'importing example with val : {val}')
```

output:

```
importing example with val : 10
importing example with val : 20
```

No clue as to how complex your package is, but if its just global variables, then this probably helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and found three solutions:

1. reload(some_lib)
2. patch SUT, as the imported method is a key and value in SUT, you can patch the
   SUT. Example, if you use f2 of m2 in m1, you can patch m1.f2 instead of m2.f2
3. import module, and use module.function.